# Request for research papers on the definite article systems of French and Italian

Tags: reference-request, french, italian, articles

[Extrapolating from this survey of article systems throughout world languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)), the only languages which brought the article system which originated in Ancient Greek to its fullest logical generality are French and Italian, which have a complete system of indefinite, partitive, and definite articles. Every other language is either missing one of the three categories, or in the cases of Albanian and Bulgarian, are of dubious logical consistency.

In light of this fact, where are there research papers that examine in detail the three-fold article systems of French and Italian?

Comment: How is that the “system which originated in Ancient Greek”? Ancient Greek has no partitive articles and only limited indefinite ones.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ancient Greek is the first western language that invented the definite article as something distinct from the demonstrative. They probably stole it from Hebrew.

Comment: Although not _all_ the data on WALS is trustworthy, I do like their [mapping function](https://wals.info/combinations/37A).

Comment: Is German really different than French or Italian?  *davon* is basically the same as *ne*, just not obligatory.

Comment: fullet logical generality?? What about Portuguese?

Comment: @Lambie Regretfully Portuguese doesn't have the partitive case.

Comment: Neither does French as it does not have cases.

Comment: @Lambie Please excuse my sloppy usage of terminology. Definite articles come in three types: definite (le), partitive (du), and indefinite (un). Portuguese has the first and last two but is missing the middle. French (as the exemplar words signal) contains all three.